# How to deal with different versions of PHP

Tags: php, deployment, versions

I'm writing a Wordpress plugin, so it's going to be used by different users and different PHP versions. The problem is that I found that some of the functions (like json_encode) are available in PHP 5.3 and not in PHP 5.2 or less. This creates a big issue, as most users don't have the latest version.

I want now, after getting the plugin 99% done, to do the following

1. Test my code with some kind of an app. where I can put the minimum PHP version. That App. or program would find out functions like json_encode. Not sure if that is possible, but would probably solve most of my problem.
2. Is it possible to get the native code of the PHP functions in PHP. I'm not sure if they are written in PHP or not, if so where can I get them. If not, what's the best option to find replacement for these functions. Certainly, I don't want to be re-coding them from scratch
3. What's the best methodology to implement the functions. I found some developers that check for the PHP version, while others check if the functions exist. Which one is best and why?

Would love also to read about your deployment strategies and how you dealt with that particular problem.

Comment: `function_exists()` is your friend http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re 1.) there may be such an application, but there also may be not. What you usually want to do is to keep close tabs on each function you use in the manual, which states what PHP version(s) are needed.

Re 2.) if a function is PHP 5.3 or 5.2 only, you will usually find a replacement suggestion in the User Contributed Notes or on Stack Overflow. (Be careful what you use though, a lot of the code in the UCN is *bad* - but in that case, there is usually at least one comment saying so.)

Re. 3.) it probably doesn't matter, but checking for whether a function exists is surely the safest way.

Answer (score 2):

2.Nope. They're provided by compiled extensions written in C. For json_encode (which BTW is available since 5.2 not 5.3) you can use [Zend_Json](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html) as an alternative

3.Checking if function exist is the best if you want to be 100% sure. After all, one can be running a self compiled version of PHP with not all core functions available. Check PHP version number, to know if features like namespaces, exception chaining etc are available.

Comment: Yeah, it's available since 5.2 but it's even worse since the 5.2 version accept only 1 parameter while the 5.3 version accepts two parameters. Any idea how to check for parameter existence since the function_exist won't help here?

Comment: You will run in vicious circle trying to do it like that. Just choose the lowest PHP version that you will support, and code so that your plugin works with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PEAR's

- [`PHP_Compat`](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat) to provide missing functionality for older versions of PHP and
- [`PHP_CompatInfo`](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CompatInfo) to find out the minimum version and the extensions required for a piece of code to run

If you want to provide your own userland implementations of functions or classes, you are good advised to provide them wrapped into `function_exists` or `class_exists`blocks, so they dont interfere with PHP versions providing those methods.

Comment: Most of the PHP_Compat functions are from php 4-5 which doesn't help a lot. I have checked the doc and the json_encode function doesn't exist.

Comment: @Omar not true: http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/docs/1.6.0a3/PHP_Compat/_PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3---Compat---Function---json_encode.php.html

Comment: may be that page wasn't updated? http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-compat.components.php

Comment: @Omar probably. there is a lot more in the API docs that's not listed on that page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know how Wordpress plugins work but except if you really want your to be able to run on old PHP version, you'll need to check for available function and provide an alternative, which can lead you code to be messy.

If you can, and want to educate your users, you can simply [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) function to compare version against a well tested and fully functionnal PHP version and throw a educationnal and explicative message to your end users.

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') <= 0) {
    echo 'You need to run PHP 5.3.0 to use this plugin';
}
```